# Github Pages root gives 404 with Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I've recently published my Jekyll site to Github pages. I'm using my custom domain (example.com) that's mapped to my username.github.io account.

If I go to example.com/index or example.com/index.html, my site works.

However, if I just go to example.com I get a GitHub pages styled 404 page.

I've tried having an index.html file in my Jekyll root DIR. I've also tried replacing that with an index.md that has layout:home in the frontmatter, which calls a home layout in my _layouts folder.

Does anyone know how I can get this so example.com shows content on the homepage?

Comment: I'm not sure you _can_. Look at GitHub docs. On a second thought, I think you could. Look at GitHub docs. ;)

Comment: That was my first port-of-call but I'm really at a loss. Can't see anything that tackles this. It's worth noting I'm not super tech-savvy. So, apologies for that.

Comment: Update the answer with the content of the index at root and _config.yml.

Answer (score 3):

For me, creating an additional index file named index.htm (without the trailing 'l') seemed to solve the issue.  Oddly, after creating index.htm, it was index.html that was rendered by GitHub Pages; I verified that by making index.htm and index.html slightly different.

Comment: All right. But, What's the concept behind this? Why Jekyll don't generate the file? Do you searched about it?